# Simple React Map layer not loading until mouseEnter event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

The map renders and the color fill happens too, but only when a mouse enter event happens. 
How do I trigger it on load?
I am using react-simple-maps, the JSON data is valid as it loads the map when mouse enters.
Here is the source code - [Github](https://github.com/pramanikriju/covid-19-tracker-india)

```
  const [tooltipContent, setTooltipContent] = useState("");

  const colorScale = scaleQuantile()
    .domain(props.data.map((d) => d.value))
    .range(COLOR_RANGE);

  const onMouseEnter = (geo, current = { value: "NA" }) => {
    return () => {
      setTooltipContent(`${geo.properties.name}: ${current.value}`);
    };
  };

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    setTooltipContent("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactTooltip>{tooltipContent}</ReactTooltip>

      <ComposableMap
        projectionConfig={PROJECTION_CONFIG}
        projection="geoMercator"
        width={700}
        height={600}
        data-tip=""
      >
        <Geographies geography={INDIA_TOPO_JSON}>
          {({ geographies }) =>
            geographies.map((geo) => {
              const current = props.data.find((s) => {
                return s.id === geo.id;
              });
              return (
                <Geography
                  key={geo.rsmKey}
                  geography={geo}
                  fill={current ? colorScale(current.value) : DEFAULT_COLOR}
                  style={geographyStyle}
                  onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(geo, current)}
                  onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                />
              );
            })
          }
        </Geographies>
      </ComposableMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally mutating state directly, and was not using the useEffect hook improperly